# Why axios get request hit again and again in React my following code

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

when I am reload page then this request hit again and again

```
const [adminRequestData, setadminRequestData] = useState([]);
  
  // admin Request
  axios
    .get("/requestForAdmin")
    .then((result) => {
      setadminRequestData(result.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: You should execute this only on component mount. Use `useEffect` with empty `[]` dependency array.  eg: `useEffect(()=>{  /* your axios call */ }, []);`

Answer (score 0):

This is because a function component executes the whole body of the function whenever there is a state change, You should wrap your Axios call in the `useEffect` hook

```
const [adminRequestData, setadminRequestData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {

    // admin Request
    axios
        .get("/requestForAdmin")
        .then((result) => {
            setadminRequestData(result.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });

}, []);
```

Check more about managing state in react [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)

Comment: It would be better to link to *actual* [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) rather than *some random blog*.